# Canonical dimensions in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis

Is there anything wrong if i construct a qft model with fields having canonical dimensions other than 3/2 (fermions) and 1 (scalars)? Is there any rigid constraints in qft against it? A detailed answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, if there is a dimensionful constant in the theory, you can in principle rescale the fields to have different dimensions, if that's the question. Note however, that it is usually implicitly assumed that the kinetic terms have a standard normalization.

Comment: I could not understand your response because bringing the fields back to some familiar set up may create renormalization issues if arbitrarily higher vertices are included in the model.

Comment: Rescaling should not change the status of renormalizability of the theory.